# Rails Polymorphic - controller & views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Hi I'm trying to create an event depending on the eventable type. the eventable type is either group or shop.

Writing my code, I'm currently sure that their is a better way create my routes and controller (still a rails newbie)

Is there a way to create only one new and create method pass in the eventable type ?

Models:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :eventable, polymorphic: true

class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events, as: :eventable

class Shop < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events, as: :eventable
```

Routes:

```
resources :events do
  collection do
    get :new_national_event
    get :new_local_event
    post :create_national_event
    post :create_local_event
  end
do
```

event-controller:

```
def index
  @search   = Search.new(params[:search])
  @shop = find_user_shop(@search.shop_id)
  @group = @shop.group
  @shop_events = @shop.events
  @group_events = @group.events
end

def new_national_event
  @user = current_user
  @event = @user.group.events.new
end

def new_local_event
  @shop = find_user_shop(@search.shop_id)
  @event = @shop.events.new
end


def create_national_event
  user = current_user
  @event = user.group.events

  if @event.save!
    flash.now[:notice] = "Votre événement national a bien été enregistré"
    render :index
  else
    flash.now[:error] = "Erreur lors de l'enregistrement du événement national"
    render :new
  end
end

def create_local_event
  user = current_user
  @event = user.group.shop.events

  if @event.save!
    flash.now[:notice] = "Votre événement local a bien été enregistré"
    render :index
  else
    flash.now[:error] = "Erreur lors de l'enregistrement du événement local"
    render :new
  end
end
```

views:

```
index.html.slim

  = link_to new_national_event_events_path
  = link_to new_local_event_events_path
```

new_national_event_events_path.html.slim

```
= form_for @event, :url => create_national_event_events_path, :method => :post do |f|

  div class="field"
    = f.text_field :title, :required => true

  div class="field"
    = f.text_field :threshold, :required => true


  div class="form-actions"
    =f.submit "Create", class: "btn blue"
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is just the routing you are concerned with, and not the number of actions, you can use constraints to allow a single path variable send the request to one of a multiple number of actions, this can be useful in some cases where you may want to have multiple buttons to multiple actions all reading from a single form, or if you just want to simplify your routes variable naming.

use the commit_param_routing gem and in your routes file you can write something like:

```
resources :events do   
  collection do  
    post :save, constraints: CommitParamRouting.new(EventController::CREATENATIONAL), action: :create_national_event  
    post :save, constraints: CommitParamRouting.new(EventController::CREATELOCAL), action: :create_local_event      
  end    
end
```

add the constants to your controller:

```
class EventController     
  CREATENATIONAL = "create national"    
  CREATELOCAL = "create local"    
  .....     
end
```

and then all that is left is to add them to your view file submit buttons:

```
div class="form-actions"    
  .row    
    .col-xs-2    
      =f.submit EventController::CREATENATIONAL    
    .col-xs-2    
      =f.submit EventController::CREATELOCAL
```

sorry for if its not quite what you were looking for or unclear, my first answer!

Comment: I forgot to mention this also adds a route path variable for you, and both use the same path name, keeping the routing simple, and they are just routed to the different actions through the constant you choose